# Atom - How to generate a PDF (*.pdf) from a Markdown (*.mkd) file from a command line script?

Tags: pdf, markdown, atom-editor

Atom

I have a MARKDOWN (*.mkd,*.md, etc.) file and I want to generate a PDF (*.pdf) using "Markdown to PDF" package, but from a script/command line, not the GUI.
I cannot find out how to do it?

https://atom.io/packages/markdown-to-pdf
(Packages > Markdown to PDF > Convert)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://blog.podkalicki.com/markdown-to-pdf-quick-howto-for-linux-ubuntu/)

Install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install pandoc texlive-latex-base texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-extra-utils texlive-latex-extra
```

then run:

```
$/> pandoc README.md -o README.pdf
```